# Also clone "invisible" partitions on laptop's hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone

I wanted to boost my old ASUS U32U laptop by replacing its Hard Drive with an SSD. Under Disk Management I shrank the Boot partition (C:) so it could fit on the new drive. However, I also noted some "invisible" partitions. One is 25GB and called "Primary partition" (no drive letter) and the other is 100MB (Recovery partition). I cannot see what's on these...

Do I need to clone these as well or only be concerned with the Boot partition?

This is a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: If you want it bootable without repairing it from installation media, in your case, you need to clone th MBR as well. Macrium Reflect free and many other similar tools can do that.

Comment: Is the MBR the 100MB partition or something else alltogether?

Comment: No, the Master Boot Record is not a partition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will contain things like your computers OS as recovery images, etc.  What you see as "recovery" is just enough Windows to get up and running and copies of a few critical files.

To successfully move everything, you need to clone the drive, and include all partitions PLUS the master boot record.

Personally to move your stuff over I'd use a tool that is both free and Free - CloneZilla.  https://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would advice not to do the migration from HDD yourself, but use one of
the free products that specializes in that.

Here are some that I know of :

- [AOMEI Backupper Standard Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html)
  with a
  [tutorial](https://www.backup-utility.com/clone/clone-hard-drive-to-ssd-4348.html)
- [EaseUS Todo Backup Free](https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/tb-free.html)
  with a
  [tutorial](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/migrate-windows-10-to-ssd.html)
- [Macrium Reflect (free edition)](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)
  with a
  [tutorial](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstall-5837543)